# Xcode5 : The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<AppName>.app/<AppName>: setAttribution:

Tags: ios, facebook, ios7, xcode5

Today, I tried to submit an update to my app to the store using `Xcode 5` and it gave the the warning `The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<AppName>.app/<AppName>: setAttribution:`. Before, it worked just fine, the last update was on August.

I'm using `Facebook SDK 3.2` library. What could be the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading the latest SDK version, Facebook says they have addressed this
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/273730516072926

Answer (score 12):

Also discovered that if you replace `fbProxy.userInfo.id` in your code with `[fbPoxy.userInfo objectForKey:@"id"]` then the warnings will go away.

Naughty Facebook for using a keyword as a property name!

Comment: I can't find those lines. Where to look

Comment: It's probably not in every Facebook project, so may not relate to your specific issue.

Comment: I also had to replace "link": userInfo.link -> [userInfo objectForKey:@"link"]

Comment: can apple will reject for same warning like : The app references non-public selectors in Payload/.app/: id @jowie

Comment: @DhavalBhadania if it's on a third party library such as Facebook then no. We had that warning for ages and had no problems submitting it to the App Store. I just wanted to get rid of the annoying warning.

Comment: thanks for given info.i already uploaded on store so i conform with it .really helpful your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will give warnings for any methods or variables if those are declared with same name in our application. But if those warnings are not critical then we don't have to worry about it. After all we can also provide a name which are meaningful to read :-)

We can check these kind of warnings threat with some utility apps like **AppScanner**. It will display warnings in red if we have to address it before submitting app otherwise we can neglect all other warnings.

Answer (score 0):

```
To remove warning "the app references non-public selectors in payload: birthday",

While getting FBUser detail from (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>*)user

instead of using 
NSString *FBDoB = user.birthday;

Use this:
NSString *FBDoB = [user valueForKey:@"birthday"];

Its Done, You will get the message "Validation Successful"!!!!
```