# showing warning message while uploading app on app store

Tags: upload, app-store, warnings, itunes

i am uploading an application on app store and getting and warning message
, please any on help to resolve this issue.
I have attached a screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 2):

May be like in this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/19301082 you have also use "id" keyword in your project.
So you have to use "id" as used in this solution.