# non-public selectors operationCompleted:

Tags: ios, xcode, non-public-selectors

I am receiving following warning prior to submission to the AppStore
The app references non-public selectors in Payload/myapp.app/myapp operationCompleted:

I tried to search for the 'operationCompleted' method in my workspace but can't find anything.
It seems like I am not using the method anywhere.

How should I proceed?

[image]

Comment: Search all frameworks and 3rd party libraries you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get this warning just for using a selector in your own code or third party code that has the same name as some selector that is marked as non-public. Happens to me all the time. `Never got rejected for it.`

[See this Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378484/the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payload-appname-app-app-name-dec) , [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172246/xcode5-the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payload-appname-app-appna)

Comment: Because, It's definition in your third party code. that's they have only .h file, .m file may not visible to you.

Comment: @JanuszChudzynski If it is really useful to you, give vote which make more attention for future users :)

Comment: I will do it once my app is approved.