# the app references non-public selectors in payload/appname.app/appname: _terminateWithStatus

Tags: ios, facebook, warnings, parse-platform

I am uploading my iOS application on app store and it is having some warning when i upload the app. warning is the `app references non-public selectors in payload/appname.app/appname: _terminateWithStatus` I am using facebook sdk"facebook-ios-sdk-3.8" and parse sdk "parse-library-1.2.18". can anybody guide me what should i do to remove this warning?

Comment: In my case getting error regarding "AWSAuthCore: reloadSession". I received a mail regarding uploading error from apple. The mentioned that AWS will use camera. For that i have to add Camera Permission in info.plist.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can't remove this warning. You may get this warning just for using a selector in your own code or third party code(may be because of facebook sdk) that has the same name as some selector that is marked as non-public. Happens to me all the time. `Never got rejected for it.` So you won't worry about this warning. [See this Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378484/the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payload-appname-app-app-name-dec) , [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172246/xcode5-the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payload-appname-app-appna)

And also see this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031356/finding-private-api-call-terminatewithstatus) to avoid rejection, find and remove unwanted framework.

Comment: On the next time application upload i got this message as an error and i was not able to upload application. I solved it by removing a framework added for unit testing. I added this comment just to help others

Comment: UPDATE : now is not able to upload, I can't upload the archive

Answer (score 2):

First time i got this error and then app was uploaded but with warnings but when i submitted the second version of the app at that time Apple didn't let me upload the app and was giving me error repeatedly `"Your app contains non-public API usage. Please review the error, correct them and resubmit your app"` after that i found my solution in this question [Finding Private API Call _terminateWithStatus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031356/finding-private-api-call-terminatewithstatus) Answer was not very useful for me but solution in question was very useful for me. I just removed the GHUnitIOS.framework and it worked for me. May be this info can help someone else