# non public selector in payload warning iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I developed an iPhone app, now I want to send my app to the App Store.

When i trying to upload my binary file to Appstore, i am facing this warning: `The app references non public selector in payload/AppName: number,setNumber` but uploading binary is successful.

Will apple reject my app because of this warning?

Here is my warning:

[image]:
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423971/the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payload-appname-app-appname-termina

Comment: No Apple won't reject the app for this warning

Comment: May be any third party API if you are using any!

Comment: @Retro: I think my problem is with setNumber ? but i am not using `setNumber` any where in my program.

Comment: I am using only this third party API files, https://www.mediafire.com/?yf21ns9764vslcv